# Can't create table `sakila`.`address` "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to install sakila db from  [mysql.com/doc/index-other.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) and followed instructions at  [sakila-installation.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html) which says run the schema ([/sakila-schema.sql](https://github.com/ivanceras/sakila/blob/master/mysql-sakila-db/sakila-schema.sql)) first then the [sakila-data.sql](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivanceras/sakila/master/mysql-sakila-db/sakila-data.sql) to insert data. However the moment I run the schema by the db engine, it terminates the execution with the following error:

```
 #1005 - Can't create table `sakila`.`address` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Here is the first few lines of the schema script which creates tables:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS sisterst_sakila;
CREATE SCHEMA sisterst_sakila;
USE sisterst_sakila;
CREATE TABLE actor (
  actor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (actor_id),
  KEY idx_actor_last_name (last_name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Table structure for table `address`
--

CREATE TABLE address (
  address_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  address2 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  district VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  city_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  postal_code VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  /*!50705 location GEOMETRY NOT NULL,*/
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (address_id),
  KEY idx_fk_city_id (city_id),
  /*!50705 SPATIAL KEY `idx_location` (location),*/
  CONSTRAINT `fk_address_city` FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES city (city_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have not make any changes in the db script, what could be the problem?

PS. My db ver is Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.39-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)

[image]

Comment: You would get this error if you skipped the first lines of the script, which among other things set `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`. Did you?

Comment: No really I did not skip that

Comment: **`SET`** `@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,` **`FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`**  This line in the script should set foreign_key_checks variable. What is the return from that line?

Comment: @spencer7593 That's what I thought so too. please see the screenshot added to my question

Comment: Some MySQL client programs (like PHPMyAdmin) have an option that causes a `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` statement to be executed. Note that the instructions indicate (rather clearly) that the sql scripts should be executed using the mysql command line client, not PHPMyAdmin. (Sometimes the instructions given are there for a reason.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use phpmyadmin when importing, in the **Other options section**:
unckeck ***Enable foreign key checks***.
Because if this option is enabled, the priority of the tables will be considered and the table that identifier is the foreign key in the other table must be created first, but this priority is not considered in the sakila-schema.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Before the cut and paste in phpmyadmin from the sql file be sure to open file with noptepad++ and not a windows software like notepad.exe

Comment: Please share more details. Why should that help?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to put it.

CREATE TABLE `actor` (

`actor_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,

`last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,

`last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),

KEY `idx_actor_last_name` (`last_name`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).